# AppFabric-Write Behind implementation how to write the data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am trying to use AppFabric. I have a table with EmployeeId, Name. I want this table to be cached. Can any one suggest how to do read-through, write-behind on this table?

Comment: You have to write [providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361704%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) and register them with the cache - why do you want to use read-through, write-behind? Using cache-aside is much simpler: "if your data is not present in the cache, your application, and not the AppFabric distributed cache, must reload data into the cache from the original data source".

Comment: Thanks @stuartd for the comment. I am using cache-aside only now. But msdn says updating database will be done automatically by write-behind. So i wanted to implement that.

Comment: @stuartd If cache-aside is easy, why did microsoft introduce read-through,write-behind. I really wanted to know the difference. Please clarify my doubt. It will be of great help to me.